# Spring Boot opencsv

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, opencsv

I am trying to use opencsv to parse a csv file like this:

```
name,purchase,date
TEST,TEST,2020-10-20T00:37:53.562000000Z
TEST,TEST,2020-10-20T00:37:53.562000000Z
```

I am trying to add the parsed data to a firebase database following this tutorial: https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-upload-parse-csv-file. This is my class for the data:

```
public class Records {
  @CsvBindByName
  private String name;
  @CsvBindByName
  private String purchase;
  @CsvBindByName
  private Timestamp date;

  // get and setters left out for brevity pls comment if needed
}
```

When I parse the file I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-2" Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-1" Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-4" Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of 2022-10-20T00:37:53.562000000Z to com.google.cloud.Timestamp failed.
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of 2022-10-20T00:37:53.562000000Z to com.google.cloud.Timestamp failed.
    at com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:128)
    at com.opencsv.bean.BeanFieldSingleValue.convert(BeanFieldSingleValue.java:98)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:180)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setFieldValue(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:581)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:328)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:128)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:83)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Can't convert value '2022-10-20T00:37:53.562000000Z' to type class com.google.cloud.Timestamp
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.conversionException(AbstractConverter.java:474)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.StringConverter.convertToType(StringConverter.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:491)
    at com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:118)
    ... 9 more
```

How can i fix this error? Do I need to change the format of the date column? I copied the date format from a record in the database so that format is how it should be stored in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the csv format to:

```
name,purchase,date
TEST,TEST,2018-09-16T08:00:00
TEST,TEST,2018-09-16T08:00:00
```

I modified the class that binds to the csv to look like this:

```
public class CsvRecords {
  @CsvBindByName
  private String name;
  @CsvBindByName
  private String purchase;
  @CsvBindByName
  private String date;

  // get and setters left out for brevity pls comment if needed
}
```

The POJO class for the data in db:

```
public class Records {
  private String name;
  private String purchase;
  private Timestamp date;

  // get and setters left out for brevity pls comment if needed
}
```

When uploading in the controller class I then convert the string to LocalDateTime and then again to Timestamp like this:

```
@PostMapping("/upload-csv-file")
    public String uploadCSVFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {

        // validate file
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Please select a CSV file to upload.");
            model.addAttribute("status", false);
        } else {

            // parse CSV file to create a list of `User` objects
            try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {

                // create csv bean reader
                CsvToBean<Records> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                        .withType(Records.class)
                        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                        .build();

                // convert `CsvToBean` object to list of records
                List<Records> records = csvToBean.parse();

                // save users in DB?
                for(int i = 0; i<records.size(); i++){
                   LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(records.get(i).getDate);
                   Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
                   Records rec = new Records(records.get(i).getName(), records.get(i).getPurchase(), timestamp)
                   firebaseServices.saveDetails(rec);
                 }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                model.addAttribute("message", "An error occurred while processing the CSV file.");
                model.addAttribute("status", false);
            }
        }

        return "file-upload-status";
    }
```

For details on the implementation of the firebaseServices class (saveDetails method) I used this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScsID2yPB8k)

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a try in this case that replaces the  Timestamp to Date?
like follow this:

`@CsvBindByName private Date date;`

Comment: I tried this same error just that it says cant convert to class date

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp field object is an instance from `com.google.cloud.Timestamp` package.

As @Allen suggested, you might have to look into `java.util.date` or event better, the  Java 8 time APIs `java.time.LocalTime` to get support from `ConverterPrimitiveTypes` to be converted automatically.

Comment: hm i tried this and it still get the same error (except for the class name)

Comment: Can you paste the new stack trace?